# Another Sequence of Sequences

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

Examine the following seven sequences of numbers:

> 1
>
> 11
>
> 21
>
> 1112
>
> 3112
>
> 211213
>
> 312213

**What are the next seven sequences of numbers? What is the hundredth sequence in the series?**

Puzzle by the late Argentinian puzzler Jaime Poniachik.

Source: [https://www.amazon.com/-/es/Bernardo-Recam%C3%A1n/dp/048684241X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/048684241X)

Comment: But is this *really* a duplicate, since it asks for the 100th sequence in the series, which I'm pretty sure hasn't been asked before...?

Comment: But, honestly speaking, the answer to this subquestion is pretty obvious, so I ommited it.

Comment: @z100 Ah, I see now. Still, it made me smile :) Have never followed this one past the first few terms before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next sequence defined as: no. of characters x from previous one following an x. Ordered from 1 to 9. Example: aabbb, 2a3b, 12131a1b ... So next one: 212223 and then 114213, 31121314, 41122314, 31221324, 21322314, 21322314,  ...

Comment: OEIS [A005151](https://oeis.org/A005151)